# Sqlite data enter error into table name as variable from another class

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I'm trying to enter data into a table. The table name is a variable taken from another class. I am using getter method to do so.

In my first class I set up:

```
public String getprojectname() {
    return projectname.getText();

}
```

And in my second class this is my code:

```
btnDone.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            enterproject1 obj1 = new enterproject1();
            String   pn = obj1.getprojectname();
            Connection conni = null;

            try {
                Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                  conni  = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite://C://Users//Asus//Dropbox//Admin.sqlite");
                  String query= "insert into " + obj1.getprojectname() + " (engname,engpass,startingdate,estdate) values(?,?,?,?)";
                  PreparedStatement pst= conni.prepareStatement(query);

                  pst.setString(1, engineername.getText());
                  pst.setString(2, engpass.getText());
                  pst.setString(3, startingdate.getText());
                  pst.setString(4, estdatee.getText());
                  pst.execute();
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Saved!");

                  System.out.println(pst.toString());

                  pst.close();

                } catch ( Exception e ) {
                  System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );

                  System.exit(0);
                }
```

I'm trying to call the value from a text field and from another class. Is that the reason for this exception?

> java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "(": syntax error)

Comment: Whats is in :  obj1.getprojectname(); I think this may be "". So thats why you get the syntax error, you are not specifying the table name.

Comment: Do this to check the value : System.out.println(obj1.getprojectname());

Comment: That is supposed to get the name of the table from another class by the object.

Comment: I did it and it says
java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "(": syntax error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing:

```
 enterproject1 obj1 = new enterproject1();
 String   pn = obj1.getprojectname();
```

and then

```
String query= "insert into " + obj1.getprojectname() + " (engname,engpass,startingdate,estdate) values(?,?,?,?)";
```

Whats is in **obj1.getprojectname();**? I think this maybe "". So, you are not specyfing the table name in the insert. That's why the sintax error.

EDIT:

You are creating a new instance: `new enterproject();` Can you bring the constructor of that class?. Are you sure `projectname` have data?

Comment: It should. How do I check? Because I set 
public String getprojectname() {
    return projectname.getText();

}

Comment: Try System.out.println(obj1.getprojectname()); before the query call. Also bring the constructor of the class. You are creating a new instance, maybe you dont want that and want the value of another instance created before the action is fired.

Comment: It just returns the get text value. Which is put before going to the second screen. Can anyone come somewhere else where we may chat?

Comment: I'll just do it wait.

Comment: I just did that and now it says the same thing.
java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "(": syntax error)

Comment: try to put "insert into TABLENAME (engname,engpass,startingdate,estdate) values(?,?,?,?)"; Where the tablename is the table you want. So you can discard if the error is in the sqlite or the attribute of the object.

Comment: Also, you should know you are creating a new instance. You are not retriving the text value of the interface. Maybe yo should obtain it from the ActionListener class or the text input.